# Get IIS Web Site Application Name

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm trying to get the web application name I'm currently in. (Where my application code is deployed in IIS).

I can get the IIS server name:

```
string IISserverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
```

The current web site:

```
string currentWebSiteName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
```

I can't find a way to get the web application name! Because I need to build a path, depending in what web application am I, to get all virtual directories.

Comment: don't understand how web application name would help you to get all virtual directories

Comment: Virtual Directories are into the web application. Need that name to construct my path.

Comment: still don't get it, sorry. But what exactly is Application Name ? Application pool name ? IIS site name ? or what

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Oct 23 answer only iterates through all the apps.  The question was how to obtain the CURRENT application name from an application running on IIS.  Ironically, the question above helped me answer it.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using System.Web.Hosting;

ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
string SiteName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
Site currentSite = mgr.Sites[SiteName];

//The following obtains the application name and application object
//The application alias is just the application name with the "/" in front

string ApplicationAlias = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;
string ApplicationName = ApplicationAlias.Substring(1);
Application app = currentSite.Applications[ApplicationAlias];

//And if you need the app pool name, just use app.ApplicationPoolName
```

Comment: `ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()` is not intended to be used in code (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iapplicationhost.getsitename(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;`.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following reference to your application:  "c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.web.Administration.dll"

and use the code below to enumerate web site names and appropriate application names.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

//..

var serverManager = new ServerManager();
foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Site: {0}", site.Name);
    foreach (var app in site.Applications)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(app.Path);
    }
}
```

Comment: ServerManager also has "ApplicationPools" and "ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName" which is cool

Comment: Hello how to get single site? in the above code I can see that it get the all sites and then uses a loop on it, but I want only get a single site from IIS either using its id or name. What will be the code?