# C# - How to obtain 'Alias' of application hosted inside a website in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, webforms, system-administration

I am building a c# utility for non-technical staff to do following

1. Modify custom settings file for all sites hosted in IIS
2. Copy or replace certain files / folders in all sites

**For logging purpose I need "alias" of applications that is hosted inside website.**

Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919295/get-iis-web-site-application-name-c-sharp-net

Comment: IIS has no concept called alias, so you'd better study the right terms first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Have a look at the basic settings wizard screenshot. You can have 'Alias' to your application